# How to get the result from below table

Tags: mysql

Table:

```
PNumber       PGen  PRev

Testnumber1   10    02
Testnumber1   8     01
Testnumber1   2     00
Testnumber1   3     00
Testnumber1   4     00
Testnumber1   5     00
Testnumber1   1     00
Testnumber1   7     00
Testnumber1   9     01
Testnumber9   1     00
Testnumber1   6     00
```

I want result like this:

```
PNumber       PGen     PRev
---------------------------
Testnumber1   7        00
Testnumber1   8        01
Testnumber1   10       02
Testnumber9   1        00
```

i.e want to get maximum of PGen with 00 and so on.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, 
and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have 
already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, 
and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a GROUP BY query with some aggregates.

```
select PNumber, MAX(PGen), PRev
from ptable
group by PNumber, PRev
```